# Правки php в разделе отзывов сайта на WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно убрать аватары в разделе с отзывами

код выглядит вот так:

```
// Testimonial #1
$pixova_lite_testimonial_1_person_name = get_theme_mod('pixova_lite_testimonial_1_person_name', __('Katie Parry - Aviato', 'pixova-lite') );
$pixova_lite_testimonial_1_person_description = get_theme_mod('pixova_lite_testimonial_1_person_description', __('Working with Pixova has been the experience of a lifetime. I strongly recommend these guys for their amazing support. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum.', 'pixova-lite') );
$pixova_lite_testimonial_1_person_image = get_theme_mod('pixova_lite_testimonial_1_person_image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/layout/images/testimonials/teammembru_burned-92x92.jpg');
```

Или через STYLE.CSS лучше? Я новичок